# How to disable eslint rule with create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, eslint

If I put `EXTEND_ESLINT=false` to .env, eslint stops working. It stops warning me about any rules.

I was using craco and everything was fine, then I realised that I want to build my app into single js and single css file. I was unable to do it with ejecting or craco, but it worked with react-app-rewired. And now I switched to react-app-rewired, but can't get eslint working.

I've even created github repository to reproduce it:
https://github.com/DTX-92/react-esling-test